# Generate Huge files containing sorted, random and almost sorted numbers

Tags: shell, sorting

Hey I need to create 1000 files each for random, sorted and almost sorted numbers.I did generate a file for sorted and random numbers by following shell command.

```
    vinod@localhost:~$ shuf -i 1-10000 -n 1000 > random_1.txt 
    vinod@localhost:~$ shuf -i 1-10000 -n 1000 | sort > sorted_1.txt
```

But How can I generate file for almost sorted numbers? And How can I automate generation part in order to get the 1000 files for each type of list (sorted,random and almost sorted)?

Comment: What is the definition of "almost sorted"?

Comment: Are you happy when you sort 100 files with 10 entries and append them to one 1 file ?